# Is it possible to use WP CLI to update a theme that is not in the WordPress Repo?

Tags: wp-cli

I have been looking everywhere across the Web (including the GIT Repo and Stack Exchange) for an answer to this Question.

Is WP CLI's `wp theme update` command only available for themes that are in the WordPress repo.

If this is the case, is there a way to tell WP CLI where to look for potential updates?

Comment: Sorry, questions specific to third party products are off-topic here. See [FAQ]. You can ask them using [their github repo 'Issues'](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues).

Comment: FYI I did go to their repo and their support section states the WordPress stackexchange as a place to ask questions.

[link](http://wp-cli.org/#support)

Comment: For the sake of arguments, they actually aren't pointing people to _question_ here, but to seek answers if they already exists - quoting: _please first look for an answer in one of the following resources_. FYI, have a look at the [WooCommerce issue](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/woocommerce-dumping-its-support-here-in-a-direct-menu-link).

Comment: WP CLI's own handbook is on https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/, the WP CLI Slack channel is on https://chat.wordpress.org/.

It even states that "WP-CLI is the official command line tool for interacting with and managing your WordPress sites."

I see a number of WP CLI questions, but only this one has been flagged as "off topic" and "third party products". It's third party only in the sense that it isn't specifically bundled with the core, but its a core tool for WordPress endorsed and used by WordPress itself for themes and plugins.

Answer (score 0):

`wp theme update` command initiates WP's update process for themes with an available update. Theme doesn't have to be in WP repo, but theme must use WP's automatic update process.